Problem with proxy conf randomly failing in angular
I have a front end coded with angular running on localhost:4200 and the back end (laravel) running on localhost:8042. Since I don't want to prepend all the URLs when doing http requests I thought about doing an interceptor to add the "http://localhost:8042/" part automatically, but after some research I found that I could use a proxy.conf.json file to do it:
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8042",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": { "^/api":  "" },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}

I have a guard to check if the user is authenticated, which calls the endpoint "/auth/check" (returning a code 200 with user info if authentication succeeds, or a code 401 otherwise). The problem is that that request sometimes fails, bypassing the proxy and querying "http://localhost:4200/api/auth/check" instead of "http://localhost:8042/auth/check".
This usually happened when I refresh a with, arriving directly on a route with this guard, but not everytime. I guess it have something to do with the guard running before the app is being completely initialized (which would explain the randomliness) but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to fix it.
Hope someone will have an idea to help me
